# How to clear safari history while button clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c

Could you please let me know how to clear safari history while button clicked in our app using the iOS SDK?

Comment: There is no public API for this.

Comment: Please help me regarding this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. As a general rule, apps cannot affect the status of other apps, or the global functioning of the system. iOS apps are very limited by the app sandbox. That's by  design.

Comment: ok, but my requirements in setting option to clear only safari history . could you pls help me.

Comment: NO.It is NOT POSSIBLE. You CAN'T DO THAT. I CAN'T HELP YOU. Nobody can. It can't be done. The only way an app can clear Safari's history is on a jailbroken phone.

Comment: how can we do it using jailbroken could you pls explain ?

Comment: I know very little about development for jailbroken devices, and can't help. You're going to have to research that yourself.